# JSP output of oracle date format is different between servers?

Tags: jsp, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g and when I try to pull the data thru a JSP, the date format is different between two environments. Both are having the same code. Both are pointing to two different oracle 11g instances.

For ex, server A returns as **2012-08-31**, but server B returns **8/31/2012**.

Here is the jsp portion where I am printing the date:

```
String query = "select dob from profiles";
Stement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
ResultSet rs =stmt.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()){
out.println(rs.getString[0]);
}
```

system A : 
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit
Oracle JDBC DriverVersion: 11.2.0.3.0

system B : 
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.0.0
Oracle JDBC DriverVersion: 10.2.0.2.0

Any idea why its like that? Thank you in advance.
John

Comment: Not sufficient details.Provide JSP and more details

Comment: Have you tried using `rs.getDate()`. BTW doesn't this `rs.getString[0]` looks incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the source code is same on server_A and server_B.

Try to check the JDBC_Driver.jar on those server.

you can format the date with class: `SimpleDateFormat`

hope this will help you.

Comment: How does it related to JDBC_Driver.jar ? Can you please explain ?

Comment: Our application has deployed on lots of clients, and it's experience. Sometime we faced the formation problem, or even more critical problem, and found the driver version in Servlet-Container is not mapping the Oracle DB.<br> I mean to check it if you can，but not sure it's jdbc-driver version problem.

Comment: some times the connection session to oracle will affect the Date formation. check the server region setting。    try "select * from nls_session_parameters" to found some National Language Support.

Comment: Is there any way that I can specify to use the 10.2 jdbc driver thru the JSP?

Comment: I have no idea. sorry. may be it can be specified with Java code.<br>DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
    System.out.println(meta.getDriverVersion());

Answer (score 0):

> For ex, server A returns as 2012-08-31, but server B returns
>   8/31/2012.

None of this is oracle default Date type.

For input and output of dates, the standard Oracle date format is `DD-MON-YY`, as follows :
`13-NOV-92`.

I doubt you are storing date in `String` and the input might be different.

1. Double check the stored value in the database. Are they in same format ?
   Then there is something to look up in the code.